# How to disable a cpu core on dual core ios devices

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware, cpu, chud

I'm developing an iOS music app which is quite cpu intensive and doesn't run well on mono-core iPhones (well I'm interested in the first iPhone 4 only).

I have an iPhone 5 for my personal use and I'm wondering if is possible to completely disable  one core so it behaves almost like an iPhone 4 first version.

I'm fine with Cydia or other non Apple-Approved methods.

Comment: You mean for testing/profiling purposes, not in your app, right?

Comment: @PeterHosey, could you define "chud" in this context?

Comment: @Charles: I've edited the tag wiki for that tag.

Comment: You can keep your program to one thread using `NSLock` to try to slow it down, and that may or may not keep it to one core (its complicated).  Note that the dual core is not the only difference.  Without looking up stats right now, iPhone 5 has more RAM, and I think its processor is faster.

Comment: starting a thread with real-time priority that never blocks might also do the trick - although I believe the mach kernel does provide a certain amount of resource-usage supervision to such threads.

Comment: Yes. Just for testing purpose.
I've done some research around and it doesn't seem to be possible to disable a cpu core on iOS as it is on MacOS. At least not as simply.